# this.state.age is coming blank after using moment().diff() in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Here is my code. But in render function, the age is coming correctly

```
 const newDate = moment().toISOString();
    const tempAge = moment(newDate).diff(moment(nextProps.doctor.specificPatient.Dob).toISOString(), 'years');
    console.log('const',tempAge);
    this.setState({age: tempAge});
    console.log('moment',this.state.age);
```

Comment: In first log the age is coming. but when i tried to display it after assigning it to state, it is showing blank.

Comment: @Pravin write it like this using callback, you will see the updated value: `this.setState({age: tempAge}, () => console.log('updated state value', this.state.age));`

Comment: Its not duplicate. The behaves differently with debugger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seriously suggest you read the docs of each method you use from a third party library. You can't go on just expecting behaviors. You need to be sure of the outcome, when it is executed and so on.

From [the docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> *Think of `setState()` as a request rather than an immediate command to update the component. For better perceived performance, React may delay it, and then update several components in a single pass. React does not guarantee that the state changes are applied immediately.*

Comment: When i display it without debugger is on it shows blank, But when i start the debugger it is showing correctly in screen. In either case the log is coming blank